# Не работает корзина на Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, корзина

**Проблема**: если зайти под одним пользователем, допустим, это вы, и добавить пару товаров из магазина в корзину, а затем выйти и зайти под другим пользователем (заранее регистрируем), то список товаров переходит к новому пользователю. Таки образом товары сразу на все учетные записи переходят.

Пробуем с очисткой кэша, проблема остается. Используется плагин woocommerce. Уже 3 день ломаю голову, не могу понять, как решить эту проблему. Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: вполне нормальное поведение, обычно используется, когда пользователь в первый раз пришел на сайт, положил товары в корзину, а только потом зарегистрировался, при этом сохранив товары в корзине, если хотите от этого избавиться - ищите место где товары из корзины сохраняются в cookie или сессии (не знаю где точно)

Comment: Корзина сохраняет все данные в куки.

Comment: Будьте добры помогите с этим, где именно нужно искать

Comment: Сервер отдаёт заголовок "Pragma"? Если я правильно понял проблему, то возможно из-за этого.